# Rendering django tag in HTML not working

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi guys I am trying to make my HTML work but it seems that I do not get something.

My HTML is the following:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Welcome to your Project {{  project.name }} Detail page</h2>
  </div>

<!-- case 1 = if there is not team created or linked -->
  {% if project.team_id == None  %}
    <div class="invite-team">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="jumbo-text">
          <h3>Your project has been created, It is time to link a team or create a new for your project</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="jumbo-button">
            <a href="{% url 'website:team_select'%}" class="btn btn-default" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
            <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Create a new team</a>
          </div>
      </div>

<!-- case 2 = if there is a team created but no team members -->

{% elif project.team_id and project.team_id.members.count == 0 %}
<div class="invite-teammembers">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="jumbo-text">
      <h3>The team {{ project.team_id }} has beed created, we now need to add TeamMembers</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="jumbo-button">
        <a href="{% url 'registration:team_register3' %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>   Add Team Members</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- any other situation -->
  {% else %}
    <h1>Youhouu</h1>

  {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

My views for linking a project: ( linked to the url website:team_select )

```
def TeamSelect(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            data = select_form.cleaned_data['team_choice']
            obj2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin=request.user)
            obj3 = obj2.latest('id')
            if obj3.team_id == None:
                obj3.team_id = data
                obj3.save()
                obj4 = obj3.team_id
                obj5 = obj4.members.all()

                for i in obj5:
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': i.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = i.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'test')
                return render(request,'project_details.html')
            else:
                print('this project has already a team')
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')

    else:
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })
```

My HTML is not rendering like it is supposed to. I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'project.team_id.members.count()'
```

the thing is using the shell `project.team_id.members.count() == 0` is true 
but `project.team_id.members.count == 0` is `False`.

How can I make it work ?

Comment: If not 0, what is the value if you do `{{project.team_id.members.count}}`?

Comment: I am not sure of you question .. but the value can be any positive integer .. it is counting the number of team members in a team

Comment: OK - could you try `{% if project.team_id.members|length == 0 %}` - the [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/) filter should take care of counting the number of elements in `project.team_id.members`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
{% if not project.team_id and project.team_id.members.count == 0 %}
```

and to `{% else %}` instead of `{% else project.team_id.members.count() > 0 %}` (which is not valid).

Notice the lack of `()` after the `count` call.

That's the way you call the `count` function from the HTML templates. In fact, any function, not only this one. Have a read in the [`behind the scenes`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#variables) on how the dot (`.`) operator works inside the Django templates.

Comment: Basically, you don't need parens on function calls in a view. :)

Comment: I tried but not working the {% else %} part. Do you think it is because when a team is linked I call a render function in order to come back to the detail page  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the else clause is not working"? The `else` clause will be executed if there is a `project.team_id` **and** the `project.team_id.members.count` is anything else but zero (thus, greater than zero).

Comment: I mean that I just tried again and even if I have a team_id and members within that team ID I get redirected to the case 1 ( see edited code ). Maybe its come from the way I render my page after creation or link I will show you my views as well

Comment: That is true. You' re not rendering the page correctly. In fact, when you `return render(request,'project_details.html')` you are not passing a `context` in order for the template to be properly rendered with the `context`'s values. So, the `{{  project.name }}`, where the `project` comes from? It does not get passed as `context` via the `render` method.

Comment: Ok got it ;) I used finally a return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk':a3.id})) thx for your help nik_m :)